# Populating new variable from ddply within old data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I have a `data.frame` which looks like this (in reality 1M rows):

`> df

```
             R.DMA.NAMES quarter     daypart allpersons.imp rate                    station  spot.id
1 Wilkes.Barre.Scranton.Hztn  Q22014   afternoon            0.0   30                       WSWB 13048713
2                  Nashville  Q12014   primetime            0.0   50              COM NASHVILLE 11969260
3             Seattle.Tacoma  Q12014   primetime            6.1   51 ESPN SEATTLE, EVERETT ZONE 11898905
4               Jacksonville  Q42013 late fringe            2.3  130          Jacksonville WAWS 11617447
5                    Detroit  Q22014   overnight            0.0    0                       WKBD 12571421
6         South.Bend.Elkhart  Q42013   primetime           11.5  325                       WBND 11741171`
```

> dput(df)

```
structure(list(R.DMA.NAMES = c("Wilkes.Barre.Scranton.Hztn", 
"Nashville", "Seattle.Tacoma", "Jacksonville", "Detroit", "South.Bend.Elkhart"
), quarter = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("Q12014", 
"Q22013", "Q22014", "Q32013", "Q32014", "Q42013"), class = "factor"), 
    daypart = c("afternoon", "primetime", "primetime", "late fringe", 
    "overnight", "primetime"), allpersons.imp = c(0, 0, 6.1, 
    2.3, 0, 11.5), rate = c(30, 50, 51, 130, 0, 325), station = c("WSWB", 
    "COM NASHVILLE", "ESPN SEATTLE, EVERETT ZONE", "Jacksonville WAWS", 
    "WKBD", "WBND"), spot.id = c(13048713L, 11969260L, 11898905L, 
    11617447L, 12571421L, 11741171L)), .Names = c("R.DMA.NAMES", 
"quarter", "daypart", "allpersons.imp", "rate", "station", "spot.id"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am using a ddply function to perform a calculation:

```
ddply(df, .(R.DMA.NAMES, station, quarter), function (x) {
cpi = sum(df$rate) / sum(df$allpersons.imp)
})
```

This creates a new data.frame which looks like this:

```
   R.DMA.NAMES                    station quarter        V1
1                    Detroit                       WKBD  Q22014       NaN
2               Jacksonville          Jacksonville WAWS  Q42013 56.521739
3                  Nashville              COM NASHVILLE  Q12014       Inf
4             Seattle.Tacoma ESPN SEATTLE, EVERETT ZONE  Q12014  8.360656
5         South.Bend.Elkhart                       WBND  Q42013 28.260870
6 Wilkes.Barre.Scranton.Hztn                       WSWB  Q22014       Inf
```

What I'd like to do is create a new column called "cpi" in my original `df` i.e. the applicable "cpi" value should appear against the particular row. Of course, the same value will repeat many times i.e. 8.36 will appear for every row which contains "Seattle.Tacoma" for R.DMA.NAMES, "ESPN SEATTLE, EVERETT ZONE" for station and Q12014 for quarter. I tried several things including:

```
transform(df, cpi = ddply(df, .(R.DMA.NAMES, station, quarter), function (x) {
cpi = sum(df$rate) / sum(df$allpersons.imp)
})
```

But this didn't work ! Can someone explain . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform` within `ddply`:

```
ddply(df, .(R.DMA.NAMES, station, quarter), 
      transform, cpi = sum(rate) / sum(allpersons.imp))
```